# Switch Mediaelement control

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have one page which contains 2 Media Element Control, first I use one Media Element control to play video(play success) and then I use second Media Element control to play mp3 file but it's not play. I tried to set source = null, call function Stop() to stop first Media Element but Second Media Element is not play. Any body here can help me?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple MediaElements do not seem to be supported, as documented here :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426928(VS.96).aspx

Hope this helps.

Paul Diston

Answer (score 0):

Multiple MediaElements are not supported but you can use the XNA SoundEffect and the MediaElement.

[Playing video and audio at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802429/playing-background-audio-and-video-both-at-same-time/8807626#8807626)