# MediaElement stops background audio

Tags: windows-phone-7, mediaelement

I use MediaElement to play video in my app, and have a question about it.
When i try to start play video in MediaElement, it stops (pauses) music playing in Background. That is a reason of fail my app certicication in App Hub. How to win this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to ask the user if he wants to stop the music with something like this:

```
if (MediaPlayer.State == MediaState.Playing)
{
    MessageBoxResult Choice;
    Choice = MessageBox.Show("Media is currently playing, do you want to stop it ?", "Stop Player", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
    if (Choice == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
        MediaPlayer.Stop();
        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, it's fine, but I want to play video independently from Zune background music. My video have no sound track, and I think it should not interfere with playing sound. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Maybe this can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802429/playing-background-audio-and-video-both-at-same-time

Comment: don't use this at all for wp7. Using the XNA sound effects.