# How to play audio and video from two different sources?

Tags: c#, audiovideoplayback

I have some movies encoded by an app that separates the audio and the video in two different files. I need to write an app to play this two files together in the same time like a normal movie and also to add subtitles.

Any ideas? or a piece of code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802429/playing-background-audio-and-video-both-at-same-time) can point you in the right track.
If XNA does it for you it makes sense.  Many games have that need for video and audio from separate sources.